# Is there a way to perform parallel operation on enumerated object (IDataReader) using TPL?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a enumerated object which I am currently using it with

```
int count=0;
string key= string.Empty
string prv_Key = string.Empty
while(source.MoveNext())
{
   count++;
   key = source["ItemId"]
   --- 
   ---- Some logic ---
   prv_Key = key;
}
```

Can I convert this above code to TPL with thread-safe??
Note : I don't have count for number of rows for source object

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows there's an `IEnumerator<T>` in scope, but let's assume you also have the `IEnumerable<T>` that was used to create the enumerator.

You can use `Parallel.ForEach` to parallelize the loop, and `Interlocked.Increment` to atomically increment the `count`.

Also, from what you've shown, it seems there's no reason to declare both strings outside the loop. Unless you need these variables to be shared across threads, don't.

```
int count = 0;

Parallel.ForEach(items, i => {

    int newCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

    string key = source["ItemId"]
    string prv_Key = string.Empty;
});
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you use `count` inside the loop, it might behave erratically.

Comment: @svick That's a good point. I added a `newCount` var that captures the result of `Increment` as a hint for the reader.

Comment: An additional concern is that IDataReader mutates the _same object_ as it iterates, meaning you may want an additional projection to avoid munging the data.

Comment: @dcastro,@Joel Coehoorn, I am using IDBManager to fetch data from SQL server which returns result as IDataReader. I cannot cast it into IEnumerable which would take hell lot of time as data is quite huge. Here I am trying to achieve to map the result returned from DB.OpenQueryForRead(ReadCommand) to my Entity. To complete that task quickly I was trying to use TPL. Is there any other way make this work using TPL? Thanks in advance